# Shuffling with Awk

Tags: linux, algorithm, bash, shell, awk

I have an array that needs to be shuffled and I would like to optimize the speed of this algorithm by using Awk. I'm still relatively new to using Awk and I was trying to figure out the best way of simulating this algorithm. How can this properly be done?

**Bash Shuffle:**

```
 shuffle() {

 local size limit rand i

 size=${#password[*]}
 limit=$(( 32768 / size * size))

 for ((i=size-1; i > 0; i--)); do
   while (((rand=$RANDOM) >= limit)); do :; done
   rand=$((rand % (i+1)))
   tmp=${password[i]}
   password[i]=${password[rand]}
   password[rand]=$tmp
done
}
```

**Awk Attempt:**

```
shuffle() {

local size limit rand i

size=${#password[*]}
limit=$(( 32768 / size * size))

awk -v rand=$RANDOM 'BEGIN {
  srand(rand);
  for(i=size-1; i>0; i--) {
    while(rand >= limit);
    rand=rand % i + 1;
    tmp=password[i];
    password[i]=password[rand];
    password[rand]=tmp;
  }
}'
}
```

Comment: `password` is a bash variable, you can't access (much less alter) it from awk like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awk has the `rand` function, which generates a random number between 0.0 and 1.0 (actually, strictly less than 1.0). To get a random integer in the range `[0, i+1)`, use `int(rand()*(i+1))`. I don't think `srand` does what you think it does; `srand` sets the "seed" for awk's random number generator, which avoids generating the same random number sequence every time you invoke `awk`. Normally, the seed is set from something which changes frequently, like the time -- although that's not ideal -- or a value extracted from `/dev/random`.

A couple of observations:

1) I understand that your loop

```
while (((rand=$RANDOM) >= limit)); do :; done
```

is attempting to avoid bias in the random number generated by `$RANDOM`, since that number only has 16 bits and thus the bias might be noticeable. However, it will only avoid bias the first time through the loop, when `i+1 == size`, since `limit` was computed based on `size`. After that, `limit` will be the wrong value. You could improve the computation, or you could generate a random number with more random bits by using `/dev/urandom`, but personally I'd just use the `shuf` utility, which does what you want (randomly shuffles an input). Of course, that's more pragmatic than didactic; it's not as educational as writing your own shuffler.

2) That applies equally to the `awk` solution (i.e., why use `awk` when you can use `shuf`?). But in any event, assigning the `awk` variable `rand` from the `bash` magical `$RANDOM` does not make `rand` magical. `awk` and `bash` aren't linked in any way. (And you can't just use bash variables like `limit` in an awk script either.)

Comment: I really appreciate this explanation, would you mind showing me exactly how to do this? @rici

Comment: @Dford.py: exactly how to do exactly what?

Comment: I've been stuck trying to make the results more secure. Like you said, the while loop is only valid for the first pass. How exactly can I make it accomodate for all of the iterations? @rici

Comment: @Dford.py: If you're using this in production, use `shuf`. It's much better. For didactic purposes, the bash answer is to compute the rejection value every time you need a random number, like this: `while (( (rand=$RANDOM) < 32768 %  (i+1) )); do :; done; rand=$(( rand % (i+1) ))`. But I repeat: use `shuf`

Comment: Got it. I really wanted to see how this algorithm worked, especially on the security side. I found this link as well: http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/arts/jsw_art_rand.aspx @rici

Answer (score 0):

As you are looking to improve speed... Instead of using either of these approaches, the "shuf" utility should provide the preferred implementation of random shuffle.

```
password=( $(printf '%s\0' "${password[@]}" | shuf -z | xargs -0) )
```

If security of the shuffle is a concern, use of an external random source is optional (at the possible expense of execution speed).

```
password=( $(printf '%s\0' "${password[@]}" | shuf -z --random-source=/dev/random | xargs -0) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an awk implementation of shuffle:

File **a.awk**:

```
function get_rand(max) {
return int(rand()*max)
}

function get_array_length(a) {
 k=0    
 for( i in a) k++
  return k
}

function arr2str(a) {
astr="" 
 for(i in a) 
  astr=((astr)(a[i])" ")  
return astr 
}

function shuffle_array(in_array) { 
array_size=get_array_length(in_array);
 ## Initialize the random indexing array
for (i=1;i<=array_size;i++) 
 rand_select[i]=in_array[i]
ridsz=array_size 
for(i=1;i<=array_size;i++) { 
 ridx=get_rand(ridsz)+1;
 newarr[i]=rand_select[ridx];
 rand_select[ridx]=rand_select[ridsz] ## Move last element, preserve indx
 delete rand_select[ridsz];
 ridsz--; 
}
return arr2str(newarr); 
}

BEGIN {
"date +%N"|getline rseed; 
srand(rseed);
close("date +%N");
split(vstr, varr, " "); 
split(shuffle_array(varr),shuf_varr, " ");
for (element in shuf_varr) 
  print "got:",shuf_varr[element]
}
```

Then call it like this: `awk -vvstr="$(echo {1..10000})" -f /path/to/a.awk`

It's not much optimized, I'll leave anything further up to you -- on my machine it's running at ~0.25 seconds per 10000 records.